# PHP, mysql, fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I need to display images on a pdf using php and fpdf from mysql database,

Am kind of new with php kindly assist.

The last part is for fetching the image to the pdf
See below my code.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$sql = "SELECT id as profile_ID,name,gender,age,marital FROM profile p where id = 9";
$resultset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:".   mysqli_error($db));

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
//require('mem_image/mem_image.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(100, 16, "profile");
$pdf->Ln();
while ($field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($resultset)) {

$pdf->Cell(30,6,$field_info->name,1);

}
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) 
{
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($rows as $column) {
$pdf->Cell(30,6,$column,1);
}
}

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$sql = "SELECT id as relative_id, trg as profile_id, Name, social as       social_media FROM relatives r" ;
$resultset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:".     mysqli_error($db));
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(100, 16, "Relatives");
$pdf->Ln();
while ($field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($resultset)) {

$pdf->Cell(30,6,$field_info->name,1);

}
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) 
{
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($rows as $column) {
$pdf->Cell(30,6,$column,1);
}
}
$pdf->Ln();
```

//fetching the image to pdf 
    $sql = "SELECT file FROM tbl_uploads t where id =1";
    $resultsset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:".       mysqli_error($db));

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
// Get the image from each row
$url = $row['url'];

// Place the image in the pdf document
$pdf->Image($url);
$pdf->MemImage($image, 50, 30);
}


$pdf->Output('Profile.pdf','i');

?>
```